# Gmail IMAP NOT command improperly implemented?

Tags: email, search, gmail, imap

The following IMAP session seems to indicate a bug in Gmail's implementation of IMAP:

```
T SEARCH NOT X-GM-RAW "-label:drafts"
* SEARCH 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
T OK SEARCH completed (Success)
T SEARCH X-GM-RAW "-label:drafts"
* SEARCH 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
T OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

Note this behavior does not reproduce if I use a different argument to `X-GM-RAW`:

```
T SEARCH NOT X-GM-RAW "label:drafts" 
* SEARCH 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
T OK SEARCH completed (Success)
t SEARCH X-GM-RAW "label:drafts"
* SEARCH 9
t OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

`X-GM-RAW` is of course a Gmail IMAP extension (documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions)), but its results should be opaque.

I am the only person with credentials to the account being tested. No mail should be moved while I am testing and I have verified that I am the only person who has accessed the account.

Is this actually buggy behavior or am I misunderstanding IMAP?

In any case a reasonable patch seems to be to only use the positive search `label:drafts` and invert it in the IMAP layer, not within the raw search itself.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  I suspect it's probably something in their algorithm like: `if NOT_IN_SEARCH: invert=true; if '-' in string: invert=true`.  But who knows.  Gmail deviates from the spec in a few places, and this seems like a corner case.

Answer (score 1):

It is their extension, and while I agree that it is reasonable to expect it to work as any other IMAP search term, you are apparently hitting some bug in their code. I suggest reporting it to them (they do read the ietf-imapext mailing list).